# How to use an asynchronous validation function with the flutter_login package

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I'm trying to use the [`flutter_login` package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_login). The `FlutterLogin` widget it provides accepts a `userValidator` field, which accepts a custom function that should have a return type of `String?` (`null` is returned if the username is valid, if not, then an error message e.g. 'invalid username').

The problem is that my validation process involves asynchronous steps (as I have to check with my backend database). So assuming a function body for the `userValidator` field like so:

```dart
static Future<String?> usernameValidator(username) async {
  bool validated = await myAPI.validateUsername(username);

  if (validated) {
    return null;
  }
  return 'invalid username';
}
```

This throws an error as the function expects `String?` and not `Future<String?>`:

```
"The argument type 'Future<String?> Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function(String?)?'."
```

So I tried to workaround the issue of returning a `Future` by using `.then()`:

```dart
static String? usernameValidator(username) {
  myAPI.validateUsername(username).then((val) {
    if (val) {
      return null;
    }
    return 'invalid username';
  });
}
```

However, it seems that anything returned inside the body of `.then()` doesn't return from the outside function, i.e. `userValidator` doesn't actually return `'invalid username'`.

I'm sure this must have a trivial solution I'm not seeing, since this is a really popular package and validating usernames and emails must surely require asynchronous processes as long as a backend is involved. What's the solution?

Comment: @lava how is that different from my attempt with `.then()` as shown in the last code snippet?

Comment: print() and see what you received? then you can capture the problem.

Comment: @A.Sang @A.Sang I'm sorry, print what? if you mean the result of `usernameValidator`,  it's simply `null` all the time regardless of what i actually return after `myAPI.validateUsername` completes.

Comment: validateUsername() what returns ? please put your code , then can solve anyone.

Comment: static Future<bool> validateUsername(username){

  }

Comment: @A.Sang yes it returns a Future<bool>

Comment: put your main code